# Move few elements from list to a vector

Tags: c++, move-semantics

I am planning to move some elements from a list to the target container(say vector) for further processing. Is it safe to use `move_iterator` for moving to target And `erase` the *moved section* of the source container?

```
#include<list>
#include<vector>
#include<iterator>
struct DataPoint {};
int main() {
    std::list<Datapoint> d_data; // source
    std::vector<Datapoint> v2;   // target
    v2.insert(v2.end(), 
              std::make_move_iterator(d_data.begin()), 
              std::make_move_iterator(d_data.begin() + size)
             );
    d_data.erase(d_data.begin(), d_data.begin() + size);  // safe? necessary?
    //...
    //d_batch->addData(v2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: why use a list   at all? almost always the wrong container

Comment: Code looks fine to me, and yes you need to erase if you don't want those moved from elements in the list anymore.

Comment: http://www.sscce.org/

Comment: i didn't give it a downvote - in fact i can't. but i can try to discourage people from using linked lists in general

Comment: @NeilButterworth my idea was to use std::list::splice to move-append the newly produced list to the other without copying. There are no random access and the total size of the container(s) can reach a few thousands, that is why decided not to go for a vector. Is it good decision? any alternative?

Comment: `datapoints.insert` looks wrong and you probably also want to move into `d_batch` in the followup. The `erase` call is necessary to not leak the dead/moved objects in the list.

Comment: well, to splice a list you generally do need pseudo-random access, via pointer following, to get to the splice point. and a few thousand is not much.

Comment: @NeilButterworth ok. I will use vector then. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: What happens on accesing the moved-from objects depends on the "move-ctor" and "move-assign" from you `DataPoint`. I have done an example to illustrate this: https://godbolt.org/z/6899oMW3x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may find `std::move` easier to use.

And yes, you do need to erase the moved elements in the source container.

[[Demo]](https://godbolt.org/z/bMdTxPfK1)

```cpp
#include <algorithm>  // move
#include <fmt/ranges.h>
#include<list>
#include<vector>
#include<iterator>  // back_inserter

int main() {
    std::list<int> l{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};  // source
    std::vector<int> v;  // target
    auto begin_it{std::next(l.begin())};
    auto end_it{std::prev(l.end())};
    std::move(begin_it, end_it, std::back_inserter(v));
    fmt::print("l before erase: {}\n", l);
    l.erase(begin_it, end_it);
    fmt::print("l after erase: {}\nv: {}\n", l, v);
}

// Outputs:
//
//   l before erase: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
//   l after erase: [1, 5]
//   v: [2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is it safe to use move_iterator for moving to target And erase the moved section of the source container?

Yes both are true, you can move objects from container and all objects which has been removed become "valid but unspecified state". So, if you want to re-use them, you can assign new values and can use it. If not needed, you can erase them safely.